# Extract files with umlaut in 7zip file created under windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, encoding, 7-zip, debian-wheezy

I want to extract a large backup of my hard drive compressed with 7zip under Windows to my Debian Wheezy installation. I'm using the following command line:

```
7z x -pmypasswordhere file.7z
```

If there's now a file or a folder called *Äpfel* (German for apples) the result on the Linux hard drive is *Ã¤pfel*.

How can I solve this issue? I tried using the following, but this says that the command line is invalid:

```
7z x -scsWIN -pmypasswordhere file.7z
```

...where the `-scs` switch is explained as: "-scs{UTF-8 | WIN | DOS}: set charset for list files".

I've compressed the file on Window 8 on a NTFS partition with 7z 9.30 64bit. The options were compression strength is *Ultra*. I've encrypted file names and their contents with AES-265. My Debian Wheezy installation is german, so *echo $LANG* is "de_DE.UTF-8".

Comment: It seems that there is something special with your setup. I just tried to zip a file `Äpfel.txt` with current `7-zip` (9.20) under windows; get it from `http://download.mpy.de/apples.7z`. I neither have a problem with an ancient linux version of 7z (4.57, dated in 2007) nor with the version 9.04 (from debian squeeze?). In both cases `Äpfel.txt` gets extracted correctly. Does the locale string (`locale=de_DE.UTF-8`) given by 7z when started without arguments is correct in your case? What does `echo $LANG` say?

Comment: Please look at the most recent edit I've made in the start post. When I'm using your example, I get the same result. There's something interesting: http://img.xn--mg-eka.de/fe997.png. On the left side is Putty, on the right side is my FTP client. The first "Äpfel.txt" in Putty is the file of your 7z file. The "?pfel.txt" is the file created with the FTP client. The interesting story: if I do the same in another directory, it works like expected... I think it's a more general problem I have too look into, nothing that is related to 7z. Thanks anway!

Comment: I rechecked with with AES-265 encryption, this does not break anything. (However I forgot to mention that I can only test with Win XP right now.) I cannot follow your story with FTP completely, but in my experience (graphical) FTP or SSH clients are always a pain in the neck when it comes to uncommon characters. Can you use `scp` instead or mount a windows share?

Comment: I've tried it. Everything that looks okay in my FTP client looks okay in WinSCP and vice versa. Everything that looks okay in Putty looks wrong in both WinSCP and my FTP client.

Comment: I'm sure the graphical client is the problem. E.g. for WinSCP the FAQ (http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_environment#utf) states: ,,UTF-8 is not supported with SCP protocol.''

Comment: You're right. I think it's okay then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "äpfel" to become "Ã¤pfel", it would be necessary to get äpfel{UTF-8} and convert it using ISO-8859-15 to UTF8. Then you would get Ã¤pfel{UTF-8}.

So how can this happen? (There appears to be no ISO-8859-1[5] (Latin1) in your workflow).

I believe I could reproduce this on a VFAT or NTFS partition using the `mount` `iocharset=value` option. If I set it to ISO-8859-15 and had a locale of UTF-8, then *maybe* the system could be tricked into converting filenames "in the wrong direction".

But here, your Wheezy installation is most likely `ext3`, and I'm not aware of a NLS option for ext3.

Another possibility is that the files are actually *correctly created*, and you're just *seeing* them wrong:

- is Putty set to use UTF8?
- are your FTP server (and client) set to UTF8?

I notice another strange thing: your two apple files, the one at 16:10 and the one at 16:34, appear to be displayed by `ls` using two different date formats. In one case, the year is specified.

It might be that 7z is creating a slightly unusual inode entry?

However, [here](https://allencch.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/how-to-extract-zip-file-which-contains-filenames-with-shift_jis-encoding-in-ubuntu/) is a trick using `convmv` utility that might be of help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, the question is not which is the preferred encoding. The one displayed well in putty or the one which is displayed well in FTP and can be access via a web server? I don't really know.

Comment: If you can check out the configuration of the various "channels", you should be able to make it work *everywhere*. There almost seems to be a ISO-8859-1 hidden somewhere. I'd try to run `convmv` on a small sample of files.

Answer (score 1):

The `-scs` option is only for *@listfiles* which seems to be a file containing a list of file names. It won't affect the charset of your file names.

One possible solution would be to run `iconv` with appropriate options against all your files *after* you extracted them.

Comment: What would be the appropriate options?

Comment: The encoding of your Windows file system and the encoding of your Linux file system. The former seems to be *UTF-16* for NTFS and the latter is probably *UTF-8*. Try it on your Äpfel file.

Answer (score 1):

This issue with zips has been [fixed](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/commit/73a19074dbe81fd25913dc5282825cb2ca9f8ceb) in the most recent [far2l file and archive manager](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l). For zip legacy charset detection by far2l to work properly, your system language setting should match the one set on the system where the archive was created (Windows' internal "zip folders" tool uses just the same logic), so if your installation is German, and zip file was created on PC with German language setting also, everything should be ok out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

OEM code page selection is broken in both vanilla unzip and vanilla p7zip.
There are [patches](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/issues/5#issuecomment-659165691) fixing this issue and [ppa for Ubuntu](https://github.com/mate-desktop/engrampa/issues/5#issuecomment-649217455) with p7zip with this patch applied. Those patches also support manual code page setting with OEMCP env variable.

Answer (score -1):

After extracting the file, just rename it via mv or your file browser, it won't hurt.

For renaming mass files, if you're forced to do that, you can use find (with -exec), or krename.

Comment: The backup is more than 100GB and more than 100.000 files...